# Google Search Console reports error pages when URL paths from one site are requested from another

Tags: google-search-console, crawl-errors

I have two e-commerce websites.  Both are built on Magento.

In Google Webmasters Tools for one website it is showing an error with part of the URL from one website and the domain of the other. If my one website is `a.example.com` which has a product `/qwerty` then Google is showing an error on my other website for same product: `b.example.com/qwerty`.

The second website has never had any product named "Qwerty". I have checked my website thoroughly but haven't found anything in its database for it.

Why is Google getting confused between my two sites?  How can I fix this tracking mistake?

Comment: What happens when you visit the IP address of your server with that URL path?  Something like `http://1.2.3.4/qwerty`?